Storing large amount of small files in HDD pool
I have a Z6 HDD pool with 6 x 18T drives and a SLOG, LZ4 compression is enabled by default. Now I need to store large amount of small files and I'm worried about fragmentation.
The files:

70K files totaling 70GB
the sparse part is mostly text files
they cannot be compressed at application level as they are synced from a remote
they are sitting on my NVMe pool now with LZ4 enabled, the compression ratio is 0.7, but they need to be moved to my HDD pool.

Here are the options:

just dump them into the main dataset and hope LZ4 make sure they don't mess up fragmentation level too much.
create a separate dataset with more aggressive compression.
create a zvol, this will solve the fragmentation problem but adds overhead and complexity.

Should I worried about fragmentation brought by those small files even with LZ4 enabled?

Seems 70G / 70000 is 1M each on average, so not particularly small.

Only 70,000 files totalling 70 GB? I agree with @StéphaneChazelas your logic appears a bit off.

It's a CoW, so don't worry about fragmentation: it will become fragmented anyway, regardless of compression.
What you should bother with - it's iops.
Also - don't create zvol, it will solve none of your [potential] problems, but will create additional ones.
Anyway, zfs is your only viable option to store these, so just do it. The task looks very basic.

Why ZFS is the only viable option? Other filesystems handle very well a lot of small files

@RomeoNinov I wonder if there’s an “if” missing in that sentence in the answer; “Anyway, if ZFS is…”

All I can say is "lol".
